# Kubernetes changing ownership of the volume parent directory

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-csi

I am running a non root K8s pod, which is using a PV and the following security context

```
# security context
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 2000
    fsGroup: 2000
    fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"
# volume
      volumeMounts:
        - name: app
          mountPath: /home/user/app
```

The files and folders created inside the volume are indeed owned by 1000 and 2000

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 2000   2113 Jun  7 12:34 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 2000   1001 Jun  7 12:34 package.json
```

but the parent directory `/app` is owned by root instead of UID 1000

```
drwxrwxrwx 5    0    0  8 Jun  7 12:34 app
```

I tried creating the app folder beforehand with the right ownership and permissions, but it's getting overridden, as the volume is created by the K8s csi.

Actually in the [documentation stated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod), that the parent directory should also be owned by the GID 2000

> The owner for volume /data/demo and any files created in that volume
> will be Group ID 2000.

How can i force Kubernetes to respect the ownership of the parent directory? Is that handled by the CSI?

I am using [Rook](https://rook.io/) as storage class.

Answer (score 0):

When mounting volumes the pre-existing files and directories will be overwritten by the CSI.

I'm not sure where the permissions on the mounted directories are coming from; my guess is that it's simply the UID of the FS provisioner, *but this is pure speculation on my part*.

Perhaps a solution is to provision the directories you want yourself; you could use an [initcontainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) with the same securityContext setting it up, or add some code to check for and conditionally provision the directory in the main pod.